# Bug with positioning JqueryUI dialog? Dialog content moves, frame does not

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using JQueryUI to create a dialog. When I try to position it using the `.position({my,at,of})` [method](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/), the dialog frame stays put but the content moves. This behavior is somewhat different with the two most recent versions of JQueryUI.

Examples:

[jsfiddle with v. 1.10.3](http://jsfiddle.net/hDnE7/1/) - div content moves, remains visible outside of frame
[jsfiddle with v. 1.10.4](http://jsfiddle.net/CPzR6/2/) - div content moves, is hidden if outside frame

Is this a bug? Am I misusing this function in some way?

Comment: is the question why is it different or are you trying to achieve a different effect?

Comment: I'd like the frame to move with the content. Having the frame stay in one spot while the textarea moves around is not how a dialog should work.

Comment: When you use a modal dialog it typically means that the user has to interact with the dialog in some way and the rest of the application does not respond. In your fiddles you want to move the dialog based on a click on the page to re-position the dialog. I wonder if a dialog is really the piece of UI to use in this case? It doesn't seem appropriate. Could you provide more detail on what you're trying to achieve? There may be better options you haven't considered yet.

Comment: @PaulSasik Clicking on the page to trigger the move was just an example, a way to show the page before and after the programmatic repositioning. What I'm really trying to do is position the dialog next to an element which will be updated by the user via the dialog. But regardless, I think I figured it out (see answer below).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution [link](http://jsfiddle.net/CPzR6/3/)

you will need to target the dialog instead of the content

```
  $('.ui-dialog').position({my:'top',at:'bottom',of:'#dlg'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Digging into this issue further, the "right" way to programmatically position a `jQueryUI dialog` is via the [position option to `dialog()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position):

```
$('#dialog').dialog({position: {my:'top',at:'bottom',of:$('#other-element')} });
```

I still think it is counterintuitive that [`.position()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) behaves strangely, but the above is a workable substitute.

---

@nol's answer demonstrates that the reason this happens is because of the wrappers that jQueryUI places around the original div to create the frame; by selecting the wrapper element, `.position({my,at,of})` will work correctly too. This isn't ideal however, in that it relies on knowledge of the classes that the library uses under the hood.